# Log console output from pre-compiled COM object

Tags: c#, com

I have a 3rd party COM object which produces masses of information to the console window.  I need to be able to save this data to a logfile and look through it later, however the producers of the COM object have not included any way to pass a filename etc to it to enable logging.

Is there anyway of copying an output window inot a logfile easily / programmatically?

Comment: No.  It was probably meant to be used in a GUI app, VB6 was the canonical example.  So either start from a GUI app template and you have the option to not create a console window.  Or you'll have to run this component in another process, you could probably use I/O redirection to tap off output.  Do use a telephone to get the best advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use pipes and redirect console output to a file:
`program.exe > yourfile.txt`